# Application window on Multi monitor screen and centre placement

Tags: qt, desktop-application, qmainwindow

I've a `QMainWindow`, which is launched by another application.

The problem is, in a multimonitor setup, the application launching my `QMainWindow`, might reside on the 3rd screen, but my window will always launch on the first.

I worked around this in the following way...

```
QDesktopWidget *m = new QDesktopWidget();
QPoint p= QCursor::pos();
int r= m->screenNumber(p); //get the screennumber where the mouse is
QRect d=m->screenGeometry(r);
QPoint l = d.center(); //not the correct solution
mainWin->move(l); //move the window to that screen
mainWin->show(); //launch
```

Now, how do I launch this window in the centre of the screen. `d.center()` is not the correct way, as the topleft of the window will launch from the centre point, so it will be obscured.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
void MainWindow::CenterToScreen(QWidget* widget) {
  if (!widget)
    return;
  QDesktopWidget* m = QApplication::desktop();
  QRect desk_rect = m->screenGeometry(m->screenNumber(QCursor::pos()));
  int desk_x = desk_rect.width();
  int desk_y = desk_rect.height();
  int x = widget->width();
  int y = widget->height();
  widget->move(desk_x / 2 - x / 2 + desk_rect.left(), desk_y / 2 - y / 2 + desk_rect.top());
}
```

and usage:

```
CenterToScreen(this);  // or CenterToScreen(mainWin);
```